# Angular display a component elsewhere

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to display the full generated content of a component some where else in the html dom (although within the `app-root`).

Let me explain.

I have this code in `app.component.html`

```
<app-component-one></app-component-one>
<app-component-two></app-component-two>
```

Now `app-component-two` calls another component in it conditionally, like this:

```
<app-component-three *ngIf="show3"></app-component-three>
```

Now what it will do is that it will show the `app-component-three` data/html inside `app-component-two`. But for some reason I want that data/html to be placed/shown inside the `app-component-one`.

Is that possible?

***EDITS***

**Use Case 1:** `app-component-one` is on the left half of screen, `app-component-two` is on the right half. Some formatted and bound data is generated in `app-component-two` but I want to show it on the left side of the screen, not on right side where it was actually generated.

**Use Case 2:** `app-component-one` is outside all bounds and `router-outlet`, while `app-component-two` is actual app which generates reports. If the report is kept in there, it is not rendered properly. So I need to pull it out of the `app-component-two` component and its `position: fixed` css bounds.

Comment: Can you not simply put `app-component-three` inside `app-component-one`? and display it inside `app-component-one` based on some condition in `app-component-two`?

Comment: Please see the edits I made to the post to define it more.

Comment: @AshishRanjan your idea makes sense, it will need indirection in code using data service, but it is workable. If there was some default practice in Angular that any expert like yourself knows, it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, In both the cases, whatever data is needed for `app-component-three`, you generate that in `app-component-two` and pass it to `app-component-one`

Comment: I would say, having a shared service should do.

Comment: I think you are right... I guess I overthought and thus overlooked this solution. Please write an answer so it may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, instead of first rendering DOM and then plucking it to display somewhere else, the approach should be to keep `app-component-three` inside `app-component-one` itself.

It's just that `app-component-one` needs to know when should it render its new child, we can pass that information and any other data if required from `app-component-two` through a shared service. The Shared service may have an Observer/Observable which `app-component-two` publishes and `app-component-one` subscribes.